# How to check if scanner input contains any digit(s) from 0-9?

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner, numeric

Essentially, I am asking user to type in their name and I am attempting to check whether they typed in a digit amongst their name so that the program prints out "Please type in your first name." once more. It is very hard to handle that issue (or is it exception? sorry I am new to this). Here is my code so far:

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class scannerTrial {
    public static void main() {
        //Initializing variables
        //Setting up scanner
        Scanner inputs=new Scanner(System.in);
        String nameF="null";
        String nameL="null";
        String gender="null";
        int age=0;
        
        //Setting up digit checker
        boolean checkF=true;
        checkF=nameF.contains("0");
        checkF=nameF.contains("1");
        checkF=nameF.contains("2");
        checkF=nameF.contains("3");
        checkF=nameF.contains("4");
        checkF=nameF.contains("5");
        checkF=nameF.contains("6");
        checkF=nameF.contains("7");
        checkF=nameF.contains("8");
        checkF=nameF.contains("9");
        
        //Initiating user input
        while(!checkF) {
            System.out.println("Please type in your name.");
            nameF=inputs.nextLine();
            if(true) {
                checkF=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

What I tried to do was make a boolean for whether the input contains any of the number and if it did find a number, it would return true. Then, I would go into a loop where if the boolean is true then it loops back until the user understands and it returns false, then it breaks out of the loop. For some reason though, when I run the program after compiling it, the program just gets out of the loop even after typing in something such as "n0".

Comment: because you always set the checkF to true no matter the input

Comment: First thing, you have to do the numeric validation after the `nameF` is inputted, you are validating the occurrence before getting the `nameF`, but it is still `"null"`. The second thing is to check the difference between `"null"` (literal null) and `null` (keyword null). The third thing is to check what is regex and how to validate a String that contains a numeric value. Finally `if(true)` makes no sense, it will be always executed, do the validation inside the `while` loop, and set the value of `checkF` properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is only checking for a `"9"`, because all other checks are over written.

To fix your code (without changing it much), you must do a logical `AND`, so in English it would read like *nameF doesn't contain "0" AND doesn't contain "1" AND ...*, like this:

```
boolean checkF=true;
checkF &= nameF.contains("0");
checkF &= nameF.contains("1");
// etc
```

But what about non-letter non-digits, like a comma? You've not preventing that.

There's an easier way if you use regex:

```
String nameF = "";
while (!nameF.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
    System.out.println("Please type in your first name: ");
    nameF = inputs.nextLine();
}
```

This keeps looping until `nameF` is comprised of one or more letter characters. Because `nameF` is initialized to a blank, it always executes the loop at least once.

Comment: Or `while (!nameF.matches("\\D+")) {`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `"\\D+"` would accept `""`. Society is not there yet.

Comment: The late artist formerly known as Prince would like a word.

Comment: "You should never write words using numbers unless you're seven or your name is Prince" -- Word Crimes - Weird Al

Comment: @Elliott Agreed. Even [Seven of Nine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_of_Nine) eschewed digits.

Comment: Aha. This is the first time I hear of "regex". Maybe I was too hurried with Java but thanks! I will try it straight away and see what goes.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't change the signature of `main` (it takes a `String[]`). Second, you could use a *regular expression* to determine if any part of the `String` is a digit. Assuming you intend to check `nameL` doesn't contain digits as well, I would suggest you use a `Pattern`. A pair of infinite loops and something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Initializing variables
    // Setting up scanner
    Scanner inputs = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nameF = "null";
    String nameL = "null";
    String gender = "null";
    int age = 0;

    Pattern containsDigit = Pattern.compile(".*[0-9].*"); // .*\\d.* also works
    // Initiating user input
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please type in your first name.");
        nameF = inputs.nextLine();
        if (!containsDigit.matcher(nameF).matches()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please type in your last name.");
        nameL = inputs.nextLine();
        if (!containsDigit.matcher(nameL).matches()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Hello %s %s%n", nameF, nameL);
}
```